# egrep command not working

Tags: command-line

I need help with this command that is not working on my computer:

```
egrep "^\S+\tAA\tAA\tBB\tBB\tAA\tAA" data.frame_file.txt >> filtered_data.frame_file
```

It is creating the `filtered_data.frame_file.txt` but it is empty. Also, it is not giving any error or message.

This is a sample of the data set of **Ballen *et al*** 2019 I am working with:

```
| probeset_id   | Runner886     | Runner886     | A_batizocoi_K9484     | A_batizocoi_K9484     | A_stenosperma_V10309  | A_stenosperma_V10309  |
|-------------- |-----------    |-----------    |-------------------    |-------------------    |---------------------- |---------------------- |
| AX-123373785  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207617  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207618  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207619  | AB            | AB            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207620  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207621  | BB            | BB            | AB                    | AB                    | NoCall                | AB                    |
| AX-147207622  | BB            | BB            | AB                    | AB                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207623  | NoCall        | NoCall        | NoCall                | AB                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207624  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207625  | AB            | AB            | AA                    | NoCall                | NoCall                | AA                    |
| AX-147207626  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207627  | AB            | AB            | AA                    | AA                    | AB                    | AB                    |
| AX-147207628  | AB            | AB            | AA                    | AA                    | AB                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207629  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207630  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207631  | AB            | AB            | BB                    | BB                    | AB                    | AB                    |
| AX-147207632  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207633  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207634  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207635  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207636  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207637  | AB            | AB            | AA                    | AA                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207638  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207639  | BB            | BB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207640  | AB            | AB            | BB                    | BB                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207641  | AB            | AB            | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207642  | AA            | NoCall        | AA                    | NoCall                | BB                    | BB                    |
| AX-147207643  | AA            | AA            | BB                    | BB                    | AA                    | AA                    |
| AX-147207644  | AA            | AA            | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    | AA                    |
```

Comment: What is "your computer"?

Comment: Presumably what you have posted is a "pretty printed" version of your actual data? it's going to be hard to help without seeing the raw data

Comment: I'm sorry I meant that I am trying to run it on the terminal of my laptop and the command is not working. A workmate at the lab tried this on Mac and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you steeldriver, that's a sample of the actual raw data, would you need tho complete dataset?

Comment: If that's how the *actual* data looks, then clearly `|` is not `\t` and `| AX-147207639  ` doesn't match `^S+`. Is that what you get using `cat data.frame_file.txt` or are you showing us a data frame as it looks inside of the `R` program for example?

Comment: I'm sorry it's how it looks for bookmark. The file is a .tsv. Is it possible to upload the file on that format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you actually have a tab-separated file (not with the borders as shown), then try this:

```bsh
egrep $'^\S+\tAA\tAA\tBB\tBB\tAA\tAA' data.frame_file.txt >> filtered_data.frame_file
# ....^^............................^
```

That uses [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) so grep sees actual tab characters in the pattern.

---

You should use `grep -E` instead of `egrep` --  the `grep(1)` man page says:

> In  addition,  the  variant  programs  `egrep`,  `fgrep`  and `rgrep` are the same as `grep -E`, `grep -F`, and `grep -r`,
>          respectively.  These variants are deprecated, but are provided for backward compatibility.

---

An alternative way to filter that text:

```bsh
awk -F '\t' '$2=="AA" && $3=="AA" && $4=="BB" && $5=="BB" && $6=="AA" && $7=="AA"' file.tsv
```

Comment: Thank you very much Glenn, the first suggestion worked perfectly

Comment: Thank you for the warning